# Extract text from an encoded PDF in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

Tried extracting text from the PDF using [iTextSharp.](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp)

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;

namespace PdfParser
{
    public static class PdfTextExtractor
    {
        public static string pdfText(string path)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
            string text = string.Empty;
            for(int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                text += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader,page);
            }
            reader.Close();
            return text;
        }   
    }
}
```

Though, input PDF contains some numbers and text. PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage returned bunch of new line characters. The PDF is not password protected.

Output:    `\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n`

Snapshot of the pdf:[image: Snapshot of the pdf]

Comment: Probably not your issue...but anytime you find yourself calling .Dispose() or .Close() on an object manually, that's a code smell. It likely means you're not properly implementing the [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable) pattern. If you using a `using` statement, then it will make sure your object gets closed/disposed *even if an exception occurs*.

Comment: _"Then I realized the pdf is encoded"_ - what do you think "encoded" means, and why do you think this applies to the PDF? Why do you think "encoding" causes these results? Even if you meant that the PDF is password-protected, you wouldn't be able to open it without a password. Are you sure this table is present _as text_ in the PDF?

Comment: While I copy text from pdf and paste it on word. This is what I see: 
  I am assuming that the pdf is encrypted. I may not be familiar and using the right term. The pdf is not password protected. @CodeCaster

Comment: No, that just means it's a crappily generated PDF. If it's one-off, search the web for "garbled text copy paste from pdf" for converting it to a readable format. If you have to process many such PDFs, find a way to do so in bulk.

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question? As @CodeCaster mentioned, it is *crappily generated* (which might even have been done by design to prevent easy text extraction!); sometimes such crap can be fixed easily, sometimes not...